# ¿Como puedo incluir archivos(pdf, docs, etc..) en la publicación del instalador de una aplicación en Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Visual Studio.  Entre sus funciones está que haces clic en un *label* y abre un manual para *X* cosa, en .pdf.  Compilada y corrida funciona perfectamente. De la compilación obtuve el ejecutable para instalar la aplicación pero, cuando la instalo en otra máquina,  intento abrir el archivo y marca un error debido a que no encuentra la ruta del archivo.

Evidentemente me dí cuenta que el archivo no se carga con el instalador para copiarlo en otras máquinas.  Intenté agregarlos como elementos de la aplicación pero no tuve éxito :c

Usé como función para mostrar los documentos esto...

```
using System.Diagnostics;//Añadí este using

private void LinkLabel6_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e) 
{ 
   Process.Start(@"C:/Users/Marty/Desktop/WinForm/proyecto/documentos/raspberry/Beginners_Guide_v1.pdf"); 
}
```

Suponía que Visual Studio añadiría los archivos utilizados al instalador, pero no fue así; necesito que los muestre instalando la aplicación en otras máquinas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=VS.85).aspx) :

Y también agrega estos usings:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
```

Cambia las propiedades de los archivos importantes que quieras abrir después:
El parámetro `Build Action` o `Acción de Compilación` con el valor `Embedded Resource` o `Recurso Incrustado`.

Usa el siguiente código

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

`resourceName` es el nombre de uno de los recursos incrustados en el ensamblado. Por ejemplo, Si tu archivo se llama `"MyFile.txt"` que está ubicado en la raíz con un  namespace por defecto `"MyCompany.MyProduct"`, entonces `resourceName` sería `"MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt"`. Puedes listar todos los nombres de tus recursos utilizando el método [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=VS.85).aspx).

Una forma simple de realizar esto sería solo manejando el nombre del archivo:

```
string resourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
  .Single(str => str.EndsWith("YourFileName.txt"));
```

Comment: Disculpa, creo estar llegando a la solución, mejor dicho, estoy aprendiendo a hacerlo XD 
No sabía por donde buscar, tu propuesta me aclaro MUCHAS cosas ya que investigue más y empece a comprender, solo una duda ¿el código que propusiste abriría el archivo que estoy incrustando?
es decir... el "string result = reader.ReadToEnd();" de

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creas un proyecto de Visual Studio Installer, en el Explorador de soluciones aparecen 5 iconos nuevos, el primero es el Editor del sistema de archivos.

Este botón abre una ventana en forma de árbol con 3 ramas:

- Application Folder
- User's Desktop
- User's Programs Menu

En la primera opción, Application Folder, podemos crear una estructura de carpetas, y a cada carpeta agregar tantos archivos como necesitemos (pdf, docx, gif, png, txt, lo que queramos).

De este modo, puedes crear esta estructura dentro de tu carpeta bin\Debug y dejar ahí tus documentos, para que cuando depures, puedas acceder rápidamente con rutas relativas, que se mantendrán después de generar el instalador e instalar la aplicación en otro o el mismo equipo.

Mi consejo es que primero agregues las carpetas y documentos a bin\Debug y después referenciar en el proyecto de instalador los archivos de bin\Debug a sus carpetas finales.